# Java Button pausing graphical updates

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep

So I have a class where I have to make a program to make Simon.
I know the way I'm doing it is not necessarily the best way, However, he had some obscure requirements so that is why I'm doing it this way.

My program is close to finished, but I have one MAJOR issue.
When I press the reset button I call a method called reset which in turn sets the computer to play their first move.

During this, there are graphical updates.

When I call the reset method by itself it works as expected When I press the reset button it wates to do all graphical updates until after it is complete.
Is there a way to have the method run after the button has ben pressed?

My Main program

```
package game;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import components.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Simonish extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {


    private Color[][] ColorSwatch = {{Color.RED,Color.PINK},{Color.GREEN,Color.YELLOW}};
    private int width = 2;
    private int height = 2;
    private int panSize = 200;
    private SPane[][] panBoard;
    private int[] Sequence;
    private int CurrentSequenceLeingth = 0;
    private int SequenceLeingth = 10000;
    private Random r = new Random();
    boolean LastButtonClicked = false;
    private int LastButtonPressed = 0;
    private int sequencePart = 0;
    private boolean turn = false; //f=computer t=player
    Container pane;
    JPanel boardPanel;
    ScoreBoard scorePanel;
    private Simonish(){

        scorePanel = new ScoreBoard(0,width,panSize);
        scorePanel.getResetBtn().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    resetGame();
            }
        });
        this.setTitle("Simonish");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(null);
        resetGame();
    }

    private void play(){
        if(!turn)
            ComputerTurn();
        else
            PlayerTurn();
    }

    private void ComputerTurn(){
        CurrentSequenceLeingth++;
        scorePanel.AddScore(1);
        PlaySequenc();
        turn = true;
    }

    private void PlayerTurn(){
            if((LastButtonPressed == Sequence[sequencePart]))
            {
                sequencePart++;
                LastButtonClicked = false;
            }else
            {
                loose();
                return;
            }
            if(sequencePart >= CurrentSequenceLeingth)
            {
                sequencePart = 0;
                turn = false;
                play();
            }
    }

    private void loose(){
        System.out.println("you loose");
        resetGame();
    }

    private void PlaySequenc(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < CurrentSequenceLeingth ; i++)
        {
            panBoard[Sequence[i]/2][Sequence[i]%2].pressPane();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        pane.removeAll();
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width*panSize, (height) * panSize + 75));
        pane.add(scorePanel);
        initPanes();
        LastButtonClicked = false;
        LastButtonPressed = 0;
        initBtns();
        turn = false;
        CurrentSequenceLeingth = 3;
        Sequence = new int[SequenceLeingth];
        initSeq();
        pane.update(pane.getGraphics());        
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
        this.setVisible(true);

        play();

    }
    private void initSeq() {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < SequenceLeingth ; i++)
        {
            Sequence[i] = r.nextInt(4);

        }

    }

    private void initBtns() {
        this.panBoard = new SPane[width][height];

        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            for(int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
                panBoard[w][h] = new SPane(w, h, panSize,ColorSwatch[w][h]);
                panBoard[w][h].addMouseListener(this);
                pane.add(panBoard[w][h]);
                pane.addMouseListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Simonish();
    }


    private void initPanes() {
        //TODO
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

The ScoreBoard Class

```
package components;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unused" })
public class ScoreBoard extends JPanel {
    private int score;
    private JLabel SimonNumberLabel;
    private JLabel timerLabel;
    private JButton resetBtn;


    public ScoreBoard(int bombsCnt,int w,int w2) {
        score = bombsCnt;
        SimonNumberLabel = new JLabel("Sequence Leingth: " + Integer.toString(bombsCnt), SwingConstants.CENTER);
        resetBtn = new JButton("reset");

        setBounds(0, 0, w*w2, 3*25);

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

        add(SimonNumberLabel);
        add(resetBtn);
    }

    public void AddScore(int update) {
        score += update;
        SimonNumberLabel.setText("Sequence Leingth: " + Integer.toString(score));
    }


    public JButton getResetBtn() {
        return resetBtn;
    }
}
```

The SPane Class

```
package components;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SPane extends JPanel{

    Color C;
    Color DC;
    int x;
    int y;
    public SPane(int x, int y, int size, Color colorSwatch) {
        this();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(x+1,y+1));
        this.setBounds(x*size, y*size+75, size, size);
        C = colorSwatch;
        DC = C;
        DC = DC.darker();
        this.setBackground(DC);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    public SPane() {
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
    }

    public void resetSPane() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void pressPane()
    {
        this.setBackground(C);
        System.out.println("dsfdsfsdfsdf");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (Exception e) {} 
        this.setBackground(DC);
    }

    public void clicked() {
        this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: This: `pane.update(pane.getGraphics()); ` is probably among the worst things you could possible do

Comment: @WyattLowery Seriously?  How would that help? `JButton` is designed to be used with `ActionListener` which abstracts the mechanism by which the button is triggered

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Half do and half don't. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Again half to and half don't. Be consistent and follow Java conventions!!!

Comment: You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread in your `playSequence` method (to name one), which is preventing the UI from been updated until AFTER the `actionListener` exits. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and consider using a [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first culprite...

```
private void PlaySequenc(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < CurrentSequenceLeingth ; i++)
    {
        panBoard[Sequence[i]/2][Sequence[i]%2].pressPane();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

This is been called from within the content of the Event Dispatching Thread, which is preventing it from processing any new updates or updating the UI.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and consider using a Swing `Timer` instead, see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

`pane.update(pane.getGraphics());` ranks very, very highly among some of the worst things you could ever do in Swing (`Thread.sleep` is up there with it).

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand how painting works in Swing

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

For example...

So, this example is really basic.  It has three buttons...

- The "wrong way", which is basically what you're doing
- The "timer way", which uses a Swing `Timer`
- The "worker way", which uses a `SwingWorker`

In your case, I still think a Swing `Timer` is the best choice, as it's possible for a `SwingWorker` to get backed up with updates, spitting them all out at once, which defeats the purpose of why you might want to use it.

[image: The Sequence]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Sequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sequence();
    }

    public Sequence() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<SequencePane> panels = new ArrayList<>(4);

        private Timer timer;
        private int sequenceIndex;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            Color colors[] = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW};
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
                panels.add(new SequencePane(colors[index]));
            }
            JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
            for (SequencePane pane : panels) {
                content.add(pane);
            }

            add(content);

            JButton wrong = new JButton("The wrong way");
            JButton timerButton = new JButton("The Timer way");
            JButton workerButton = new JButton("The Worker way");

            JPanel actions = new JPanel();
            actions.add(wrong);
            actions.add(timerButton);
            actions.add(workerButton);

            add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            wrong.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Collections.shuffle(panels);
                    for (SequencePane pane : panels) {
                        try {
                            pane.setHighlighted(true);
                            Thread.sleep(250);
                            pane.setHighlighted(false);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (sequenceIndex > 0) {
                        panels.get(sequenceIndex - 1).setHighlighted(false);
                    }

                    if (sequenceIndex < panels.size()) {
                        panels.get(sequenceIndex).setHighlighted(true);
                        sequenceIndex++;
                    } else {
                        timer.stop();
                        // All done, call some "play" method to begin playing
                    }
                }
            });

            timerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    timer.stop();
                    Collections.shuffle(panels);
                    sequenceIndex = 0;
                    timer.start();
                }
            });

            SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Object, SequenceState>() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    for (SequencePane pane : panels) {
                        publish(new SequenceState(pane, true));
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        publish(new SequenceState(pane, false));
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void process(List<SequenceState> chunks) {
                    SequenceState state = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                    state.applyState();
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    // Back in the EDT, call what ever "play" method you need
                }

            };

            workerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Collections.shuffle(panels);
                    SequenceWorker worker = new SequenceWorker();
                    worker.execute();
                }
            });

        }

        public class SequenceWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, SequenceState> {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    for (SequencePane pane : panels) {
                        publish(new SequenceState(pane, true));
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                        publish(new SequenceState(pane, false));
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void process(List<SequenceState> chunks) {
                    for (SequenceState state : chunks) {
                        state.applyState();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    // Back in the EDT, call what ever "play" method you need
                }

            }

        public class SequenceState {

            private SequencePane sequencePane;
            private boolean highlighted;

            public SequenceState(SequencePane sequencePane, boolean highlighted) {
                this.sequencePane = sequencePane;
                this.highlighted = highlighted;
            }

            public SequencePane getSequencePane() {
                return sequencePane;
            }

            public boolean isHighlighted() {
                return highlighted;
            }

            public void applyState() {
                getSequencePane().setHighlighted(isHighlighted());
            }
        }

    }

    public class SequencePane extends JPanel {

        private boolean highlighted;

        public SequencePane(Color color) {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBackground(color);
        }

        public void setHighlighted(boolean highlighted) {
            this.highlighted = highlighted;
            repaint();
        }

        public boolean isHighlighted() {
            return highlighted;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (!isHighlighted()) {
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.25f));
            }
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1st Professor required a null layout, I know its STUPID
and shouldn't the sleep be called after the color is changed which is in the pressPane.

Comment: To the second point NO. You are BLOCKING the thread which is responsible for updating the UI, so until your `actionPerformed` method exists NO updates will be performed to the UI, this is how the UI works.

Comment: Also The PlaySequenc works fine when it is not being called by the button.

Comment: @KevinHall That's because when you first call it, you're not executing within the context of the EDT, which is also bad - essentially, it's a fluck, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: So how can I get around this? It seems like there is no way to have the actions perform after the reset button is called. is there a way to que the method to run after the push?

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker` to play the sequence

Comment: So i just watched 2 short videos about string workers. if I put the reset game in a sting worker class it should work? or am i getting this wrong?

Comment: Yes and no.  Swing is also not thread safe, the purpose of the `SwingWorker` is to allow you to perform some long running operation in the background, but update the UI safely through the `publish`/`process` methods

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU I HAVE 30 minutes left and ive ben trying this thing for like 3 hours and it finally works.

Comment: I've also updated with an example using a Swing `Timer` and `SwingWorker`