# Animation sequence in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, jframe

I wanted to create a `JFrame` and put a sequence of images for animation in there. But the images don't appear in the frame window. I just want basic troubleshooting tips to make it appear in the window. Just edit the code for an answer if you can.

My question:
Why isn't the window displaying any pictures? It shows a window with a background color of blue, but that's it. Please tell me an efficient way to store images in variables and display it in a loop.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;



public class Game extends JLabel implements ActionListener{


 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 public static Game blah;
  BufferedImage nekopics[] = new BufferedImage[7];

 BufferedImage currentimg;
 public String nekosrcs[];
 int xpos;

 Timer timer;

 public Game() throws IOException
 {
      JFrame jframe = new JFrame();




      nekosrcs = new String[] { "walk1.png", "walk2.png",

              "walk3.png", "walk4.png", "walk5.png",

              "walk6.png"};

    jframe.setTitle("Game");
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    jframe.setSize(400, 400);
    jframe.setResizable(false);
    jframe.setVisible(true);

    jframe.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);




     for (int i=0; i < nekopics.length; i++) {

 nekopics[i] = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("D:/Programs 
                                              /pics"+nekosrcs[i]));

     }

     for (int i=0; i < nekopics.length; i++) {
         timer = new Timer(1000, this);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
         currentimg = nekopics[i];

         repaint();


     }



 }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    g.drawImage(currentimg,100,100,this);
}



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

blah = new Game();



}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




}
```

Comment: You can see a running example of the Swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746795/creating-an-animated-4x4-grid-in-java/34748083#34748083)

Comment: *My questions:* Please ask one question per post, as you said, you're new here, so please go through the [help] and learn [ask] and how to make a [mcve] as well as how to indent your code correctly please, I already indented it, but I should be doing that, next time do it correctly before posting it, also please follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): *"Variable names should start with a lower case"*

Comment: Also why are you extending `JFrame` and creating a `JFrame` object? Do one or the other, I recommend the latter, because if you extend a `JFrame` you're saying that your class is actually a `JFrame`, instead if you need to extend something, extend `JPanel` so you can later add those panels to another `JFrame`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the images still do not appear in the window. I have performed the edits you proposed. Would love it if you could check if I used the timer properly in this new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, there are a lot of problems in your code, let's step into each of them:

1. You have a lot of spaces between lines, that makes your code a lot larger and harder to read
2. You haven't indented your code correctly (see the last `}` on your code, it's at the same level than the others; your `for` loops, etc), it makes the code so much harder to read and understand as well
3. You're creating a `JFrame` but extending `JLabel`, I'm not sure why you're doing this, if you're doing it so you can use the `paintComponent()` method, it's not necessary, on my code you can see how you can do it w/o extending any `Component`
4. If you haven't read the Swing `Timer` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer-int-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) you should click that link and read what the `ActionListener` parameter does. In this case, we're going to use this listener to call the `repaint()` method and update our `currentImage` (or `nextImage` in the code below) and change the image accordingly. You failed to do this.
5. You were creating more than 1 `Timer` too, you created 6 here! All of them new but they had no action to do when the time finished

   ```
   for (int i=0; i < nekopics.length; i++) {
       timer = new Timer(1000, this);
       timer.setInitialDelay(0);
       timer.start();
       currentimg = nekopics[i];
       repaint();
   }
   ```
6. You're changing unnecessarily the visibility of the `paintComponent()` method to `public` from `protected`

---

However I want to congratulate you for not using a `null` layout and following the recommendations I made on the comments above.

---

And finally the code that changes one image for another inside a `Timer` is the following, you can copy-paste it and change the image's names so you can see how it works.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ImageSequence {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private Timer timer;
    private int nextImage = 0;
    private String[] images = {"tokyo", "tokyo2", "starwars"};
    private Image img = null;
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageSequence().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Sequence");
        timer = new Timer(1000, listener);
        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/home/jesus/Pictures/" + images[nextImage] + ".jpg"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                g.drawImage(img , 0, 0, 200, 200, this);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };

        timer.start();

        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(nextImage);
            nextImage = nextImage < images.length - 1 ? nextImage + 1 : 0;
            System.out.println(nextImage);
            pane.repaint();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! Although there are a bunch of new methods I would have to look up for now. Gosh..I am really an amateur! I will act on your suggestions and for the next time I post here, would make my codes alot more cleaner and readable. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @noobprogrammer No problem, try using an IDE they will suggest you the methods you want, I'm not the best but I have studied swing by 4 years now (everything while reading SO Q&A), I'm actually a beginner too compared with some other users, I'm glad you want to improve your posts and your programming skills too, so, good luck and happy programming :)