# Replacing an image once through timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, imageicon

I am working on this reaction time game that tells you to click an arrow key once the ball has turned into a different colored ball. However, I can't seem to get the image of the ball to be replaced by the other ball.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game extends JPanel
{
  private JLabel watch, main;
  private ImageIcon constant, react;
  final int width = 600;
  final int height = 600;
  private Timer replace;
  private ActionListener timerListener;
  
  
  public Game()
  {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setBackground(Color.black);
    
    watch = new JLabel("Click Up Arrow when you see a blue ball");
    watch.setForeground(Color.white);
    add(watch);
   
    constant = new ImageIcon("constantCircle.png");
    main = new JLabel(constant);
    
    replace = new Timer(3000, timerListener);
    replace.setRepeats(false);
    replace.start();
 
    add(main);
    
  }
  
  
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {
    react = new ImageIcon("reactCircle.png");
    main.setIcon(react);
    
  }
}
```

This is the code for my display and I wanted to use a swing timer to replace the image after 3 seconds

This is what I want it to look like before

[image: This is what I want it to look like before]

and this is what I want it to look like after 3 seconds

[image: and this is what I want it to look like after 3 seconds]

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mre], where's your `timerListener`?

Comment: I just edited the code to show all my code to show you where the timerListener is. Also, I would try to minimize the amount of code but I honestly don't really know where the problem specifically is. I think its in the timer but I'm just not sure what to do to replace the image with a new one @Frakcool

Comment: Where are you initializing the `timerListener`? So far your `actionPerformed` doesn't belong to anything. Take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34748083/2180785) as a starting point. In your current code `replace = new Timer(3000, timerListener);` is the same as `replace = new Timer(3000, null);`

Comment: ohhhhh, okay thank you so much. I just did that and it worked! Thank you @Frakcool

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never initializing `timerListener`

```
private ActionListener timerListener;
```

Inside your constructor you have to call (With Java 8 lambdas):

```
timerListener = e -> {
    react = new ImageIcon("reactCircle.png");
    main.setIcon(react);
}
```

Or (Java 7 and lower):

```
timerListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        react = new ImageIcon("reactCircle.png");
        main.setIcon(react);
    }
}
```

<strike>And don't forget to call `timerListener.stop()` once the timer has fired, so that you don't keep computing more times</strike>

From Andrew Thompson's comment below:

As you only want to replace the image once, call `timerListener.setRepeats(false)` on your constructor. Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats(boolean)) for more information about it.