# Change the background of a panel multiple times in the same method

Tags: java, user-interface

Hi i'm trying to change the background of a panel to create something similar to the Simon color games.

Here's what I have for code. The problem I seem to be finding is that the only time the background physically changes only at the end of the button being pressed. I have tried using Repaint(); and it has had no effect.

```
 private void ClickRandomColorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    Random gen = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        int CaseNum = 0;

        CaseNum = gen.nextInt(3) +1;

        ChangeBackground(CaseNum);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Testerino.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}                                                

public void ChangeBackground(int i){
    System.out.println(i);

    if(i == 1){
        RandColor.setBackground(blue);
    }
    else if (i == 2){
        RandColor.setBackground(black);

    }
    else if(i == 3){
        RandColor.setBackground(magenta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer` or the `SwingUtilities.innvokeLater()` method. These work well with Swing applications.

Comment: And then have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727830/java-button-pausing-graphical-updates/33727882#33727882)