# I need to have a java timer inside a loop

Tags: java, loops, timer, paintcomponent, netbeans-8

I am creating a two player Simon game, one player(client) clicks the colored squares, and the client will send the clicking sequence (as an ArrayList) to the server, and the server sends it to the other player.

Right now, the ArrayList arrives at the other client with no problem, but when I loop through the ArrayList, and inside the loop, I want the colored squares to flash. Only the last color will flash.

```
public void flashArray(){
    for(int i=0;i<blist.size();i++){
        int toFlash = blist.get(i);
        setFlashed(toFlash);//for example, if toFlash==1, after repaint, the green square will be lighter, and after the timer, it will be back to normal
        repaint();

        Timer timer = new Timer(200, timerAction);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();

    }
}
```

the timerAction code

```
 private ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        setFlashed(F_DEFAULT);
        repaint();

    }
};
```

the flashing works when I manually click the squares, they will flash. but when I put the code into the flashArray (loop) it will not work, it will only flash the last color.

Comment: Have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the likely cause

Comment: Maybe something more like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727830/java-button-pausing-graphical-updates/33727882#33727882)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MadProgrammer.

Using Thread.sleep(sleeptime) is worked perfectly for me.

Here is the method:

```
    //a method to make simon flash based on the arraylist
public void flashArry(){
    for(int i=0;i<blist.size();i++){

        int toFlash = blist.get(i);
        setFlashed(toFlash);
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Simon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        setFlashed(F_DEFAULT);
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Simon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

to explain the code: loop through the integer arraylist(the integers represent the colors to flesh), set the color-> repaint (make it brighter)-> sleep->set back to default color-> repaint ->sleep ->loop to next color to flash...